# Markov Chain Example.

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

A Markov chain $X_0,X_1,X_2,\ldots$ has the transition probability matrix

$$P=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0.3 & 0.2 & 0.5 \\
        0.5 & 0.1 & 0.4 \\
        0.5 & 0.2 & 0.3
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

and the initial distribution $p_0=0.5$ and $p_1=0.5$. what is the probability $\Pr(X_1=1,X_2=1,X_3=0)$ ?

I solved the problem as

$$\Pr(X_1=1,X_2=1,X_3=0)=\Pr(X_1=1)Pr(X_2=1\mid X_1=1)\Pr(X_3=0\mid X_2=1)$$
$$=p_1P_{1,1}P_{1,0}=(0.5)(0.1)(0.5)=0.025$$

But the answer is $0.0075$. I am not understanding where am I doing mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recompute $Pr(X_1=1)$.  It's not the same as $p_1$, which is $Pr(X_0=1)$.